# randomize array using php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I need to rendomise the order of follow array using PHP, i tried to use array shuffle and array_random but no luck, can anyone help me please

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [value] => 4
    [label] => GasGas
  )
  [1] => Array (
    [value] => 3
    [label] => Airoh Helmets
  )
  [2] => Array (
    [value] => 12
    [label] => XCiting Trials Wear
  )
  [3] => Array (
    [value] => 11
    [label] => Hebo Trials
  )
  [4] => Array (
    [value] => 10
    [label] => Jitsie Products
  )
  [5] => Array (
    [value] => 9
    [label] => Diadora Boots
  )
  [6] => Array (
    [value] => 8
    [label] => S3 Performance
  )
  [7] => Array (
    [value] => 7
    [label] => Scorpa
  )
  [8] => Array (
    [value] => 6
    [label] => Inspired
  )
  [9] => Array (
    [value] => 5
    [label] => Oset
  )
)
```

Comment: how are you trying to shuffle? The shuffle function does randomize the order of elements in an array.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102777/php-random-shuffle-array-maintaining-key-value which gives you exactly the answer you want.

Comment: I just tested this an it worked for me in codepad: http://codepad.org/6MmaY81i

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
shuffle($array);
print_r($array);
```

Comment: thanks i got this wrong way before, i shuffle the array and assigned it in to a variable. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can get a random sequence of array index, i think it will allow you to resolve your problem;)

> // return random nonrecurring array of numbers
>   
> //params: 
>   
> //$fromto - if $to is null, interval will be [0, $fromto], elsewhere [$fromto, $to] 
>   
> //$to - end of interval.
>   
> //$limit - limit number. notice! if $limit < size([$fromto, $to]) not all numbers from interval [$fromto, $to] will be return 
>   
> **function** rand_seq($fromto, $to = null, $limit = null){
>   
> if(is_null($to)){
>   
>     $to = $fromto;
>   
>     $fromto = 0;   }
>   
>     if(is_null($limit)){
>   
>       $limit = $to-$fromto+1;
>   
>     }
>   
>   $randArr = array();
>   
>   for($i=$fromto; $i<=$to; $i++){
>   
>     $randArr[]=$i;
>   
>   }
>   
>   $result = array();
>   
>   for($i=0; $i < $limit||sizeof($randArr) > 0; $i++){
>   
>     $index = mt_rand(0, sizeof($randArr)-1);  // select rand index / выбираем случайный индекс массива
>   
>     $result[] = $randArr[$index]; // add random element / добавляем случайный элемент массива
>   
>     array_splice($randArr, $index, 1);  // remove it=) / удаляем его =)
>   
>   }
>   
>   return $result; 
>   
> }