# PHP randomize array which key's values are stdClasses

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to randomize an array which contains stdClasses as value for every key and the stdclasses order must be the original.

for example the original array looks like this:

```
Array(
 [0]=>stdClass(/*lots of keys with value that must stay here and stay in order 
                 for example [id]=1 [name]=One*/)
 [1]=>stdClass(/*lots of keys with value that must stay here and stay in order 
                 for example [id]=2 [name]=Two*/)
 [2]=>stdClass(/*lots of keys with value that must stay here and stay in order 
                 for example [id]=3 [name]=Three*/)
 [3]=>stdClass(/*lots of keys with value that must stay here and stay in order 
                 for example [id]=4 [name]=Four*/)
)
```

and this is what I would like to achive:

```
Array(
 [3]=>stdClass(/*lots of keys with value that must stay here and stay in order 
                 for example [id]=4 [name]=Four*/)
 [0]=>stdClass(/*lots of keys with value that must stay here and stay in order 
                 for example [id]=1 [name]=One*/)
 [1]=>stdClass(/*lots of keys with value that must stay here and stay in order 
                 for example [id]=2 [name]=Two*/)
 [2]=>stdClass(/*lots of keys with value that must stay here and stay in order 
                 for example [id]=3 [name]=Three*/)
)
```

I tried this function [PHP Random Shuffle Array Maintaining Key => Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102777/php-random-shuffle-array-maintaining-key-value) but this shuffels the stdClasses too and thats not good.
for example zero key's class->id is shuffeld to third key

And I don't know how to randomize this in the right way.

Comment: So you're trying to shuffle it, except you want the values to remain constant and the numeric keys to be shuffled?

Comment: Yes, actually I would like to achive the same like MySQL's ORDER BY RAND() does.

Comment: Are these objects indexed by numeric or string keys?  Are you sure numeric key/value association actually matters?

Comment: string as in the example, ID, NAME, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will shuffle your array and maintain key/value association.

```
$array = array('a'=> '1', 'b'=>'2', 'c'=>'3');

function shuffle_assoc($array) {
    $keys = array_keys($array);
    shuffle($keys);

    $result = array();
    foreach ($keys as $k) {
        $result[$k] = $array[$k];
    }

    return $result;
}

$result = shuffle_assoc($array);

// $result = array('b'=>'2', 'c'=>'3', 'a'=>'1')
```

Comment: Yes this does it. First I didn't realised that there was an error in the code where the original array comes from and that caused the trouble in the shuffle. Thank you for your help.