# randomise array elements preserving assoc key value pairs

Tags: php, arrays

I am building a quiz application. Pretty straight forward. Only the last bit is left and where I am stuck. I want to randomise the answer options. check see the comment in the code where I have problem in CAPS. 
Shuffle is working but it's changing assoc array to numbers 0 1 etc.
array_rand making foreach not to work and foreach throwing error. invalid argument supplied.
Don't know what is going wrong can anyone please help me..

```
        <form action="<?php echo URL?>load=quiz&page=<?php echo $page; ?>" method="post" name="quiz">
        <?php //var_dump($quiz_data); 
            $all_ans_opts = array();
            $ans_opts = array_filter($all_ans_opts);;


        ?>
        <?php foreach($quiz_data as $d):

                $all_ans_opts['answer_a'] = $d['answer_a'];
                $all_ans_opts['answer_b'] = $d['answer_b'];
                $all_ans_opts['answer_c'] = $d['answer_c'];
                $all_ans_opts['answer_d'] = $d['answer_d'];
                $all_ans_opts['answer_e'] = $d['answer_e'];

       ?>
        <!-- If the question type is MC show the radio form-->


        <p>                    
        Question <?php echo $d['question_number']; ?>: <?php echo $d['question_title'] ; ?>
        </p>
        <p>
           <input type="hidden" name="page_num" value="<?php echo $page; ?>">
           <input type="hidden" name="question_number" value="<?php echo $d['question_number']; ?>">
           <input type="hidden" name="questionid" value="<?php echo $d['questionid']; ?>">
           <input type="hidden" name="quiz_number" value="<?php echo $d['quiz_number']; ?>">

        <?php
        endforeach; 

        //var_dump($all_ans_opts);



            ?>
               <?php 
// HERE I AM TRYING TO RANDAMISE THE ARRAY ELEMENTS PRESERVING KEY VALUE PAIRS FOR FOREACH
// FOR RANDAMISATION IF I USE SHUFFLE IT WORKS BUT CHANGING THE KEY FROM ASSOCIATIVE TO //INDEX 0 1 ETC.. 
// IF I USE ARRAY_RAND FUNCTION FOREACH GIVES ERROR- nvalid argument supplied for foreach()

               $ans_opts = array_filter($all_ans_opts);
               shuffle($all_ans_opts);                     
               //$ans_opts = array_rand($all_ans_opts);

           ?>

           <?php foreach ($ans_opts as $key=>$val){ ?>

            <input type="radio" name="<?php echo 'answer_selected';?>" value=<?php echo $key ?>><?php echo $val; ?><br/>

           <?php } ?>
        </p>


        <input type="submit" name="prev" value="Previous Question" <?php if($page == 0) echo "disabled";?> />                
        <input type="submit" name="save" value="<?php if($page == $totalQuestion-1)echo 'Submit Quiz'; else{echo 'Save & Continue';} ?>" />
        <input type="submit" name="next" value="Next Question" <?php if($page == $totalQuestion-1) echo "disabled";?> />
    </form>
```

Comment: research my friend. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102777/php-random-shuffle-array-maintaining-key-value

Comment: @anurupr so there is no function available we have to write our own is it?

Answer (score 1):

The simple way is to use [`uasort()`](http://php.net/uasort) - it keeps keys when sorting. To randomize, just use random sort:

```
$array = [
  'foo'=>14,
  'bar'=>10,
  'baz'=>19,
  'bee'=>26,
  'feo'=>23
];

uasort($array, function($x,$y)
{
   //you can use `return mt_rand(0,1)` - but that's
   //unreliable, since compare function must return -1/0/1
   return mt_rand() - mt_rand();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a function in manual:

https://www.php.net/shuffle#94697