# How to shuffle list in PHP

Tags: php

I have been looking through stackoverflow, and I found nothing that answered my question, on how I shuffle a list without getting the associative arrays. Since my code uses `shuffle_assoc`I get the associative arrays, but using shuffle didn't get me anywhere, so now I turn here.

```
        function shuffle_assoc($list) {
            if (!is_array($list)) return $list;

            $keys = array_keys($list);
            shuffle($keys);
            $random = array();
            foreach ($keys as $key) {
                $random[] = $list[$key];
            }
            return $random;
        }

        $arr = array();
        $arr[] = "test 1<br>";
        $arr[] = "test 2 <br>";
        $arr[] = "test 3 <br>";
        $arr[] = "test 4 <br>";
        print_r(shuffle_assoc($arr));
 ?>
```

[This is how it looks when I run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iC6Et.png)

However I don't want the `Array ([0] =>` parts to show, I only want to randomly shuffle the test(1/2/3/4)list every time I run the code.

Comment: Why don't directly use `shuffle($arr);`

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102777/php-random-shuffle-array-maintaining-key-value

Comment: Have tried both shuffle and I also went looked at that post, , but it didn't solved my problem, however nospor's answer did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`print_r` function display data as they are. So it print array when you give it array. You need to implode your array into string:

```
echo  implode('',shuffle_assoc($arr));
```

edit:
or just

```
echo  implode('',shuffle($arr));
```

Comment: simply shuffle function can do the work, why to do such kind of  complexity? use shuffle and implode only.

Comment: no, don't update main code. just add another way which is simple.

Comment: Ok, so I've updated my answer again. I hope this time is ok :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$array = shuffle($arr);
foreach($array as $a)
{
    echo $a;
}
```

Comment: I think @TomasBerger just wants to output line on a page and shuffles them every time  code runs. So I think my code achieve his aim.