# How can I mix array's items up?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
$arr = ['red' => '#110000', 'blue' => '000011', 'brown' => '#A52A2A', 'maroon' => '#800000'];
```

And I need to make array above shuffle. There is a php function named [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) which is for this. But sadly it removes array's keys. Here is a [fiddle](https://3v4l.org/sqNh0).

Anyway, how can I both shuffle an array and keep the keys?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Random Shuffle Array Maintaining Key => Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102777/php-random-shuffle-array-maintaining-key-value)

Answer (score 4):

Try this function

```
function shuffle_assoc($array) {
    $keys = array_keys($array);

    shuffle($keys);

    foreach($keys as $key) {
        $new[$key] = $array[$key];
    }

    return $new;
}
```

Comment: You are welcome, The solution is from the first comment from `shuffle()` page on php.net, http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Comment: I thought the OP asked to keep the keys and shuffle the rest?

Comment: Maybe, if this what he want then we will made some modification to the function @nevabyte

Comment: @redFIVE it is true ;) But some times you can't notice the solution even if it's in front of you because of stress and tired. So give little reason.

Comment: @redFIVE thanks for calling me as a tpp lazy person `:-)` .. Actually I googled my problem before asking, and because of my poor English, I couldn't find expected answer.

Comment: @MartinAJ, @redFive this is another reason that didn't came to my mind before `:|`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution based on a randomized sorting and it preserves the key-value associations, as follows:

```
<?php

$colors = ['red' => '#110000', 'blue' => '000011', 'brown' => '#A52A2A', 'maroon' => '#800000'];

function assoc_shuffle ( $arr ) {
    uasort($arr, function ($a, $b) {
        return rand(-1, 1);
    });
    return $arr;
}

print_r( assoc_shuffle( $colors ) );
```

See [demo](https://3v4l.org/g806a)

There is another way which preserves the key-value associations and allows one to use shuffle(), too.  The solution entails creating an indexed array such that every element holds an array of one element whose key and value are the same as in the original array $colors, as follows:

```
<?php

function test_print($item, $key) {
    echo "$key: $item\n";
}

$arr = array();
$colors = ['red' => '#110000', 'blue' => '000011', 'brown' => '#A52A2A', 'maroon' => '#800000'];

foreach ($colors as $k => $v ) {
    $arr[] = [$k => $v];
}

shuffle( $arr );
array_walk_recursive($arr, 'test_print');
```

See [demo](https://3v4l.org/L58Y7)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php):

```
function shuffle_assoc(array &$array)
{
    $range = range(1, count($array));
    shuffle($range);
    array_multisort($range, $array);
}
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/139266e155dfd93994d9a5f390b8f28018c76fa2).

Answer (score 0):

Like this;

```
$keys = array_keys($arr);
$values = shuffle(array_values($arr));
$shuffled = array_combine($keys, $values);
```