# php arrays - save the values for all subarrays that have the price lower then maximum

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array(
  [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => E
            [1] => TIME
            [2] => 46.00
            [3] => Keck
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => D
            [1] => TIME
            [2] => 46.00
            [3] => Keck
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => B
            [1] => TIME
            [2] => 50.40
            [3] => Keck
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => C
            [1] => TIME
            [2] => 54.40
            [3] => Keck
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => G
            [1] => TIME
            [2] => 80.00
            [3] => Keck
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => TIME
            [2] => 80.00
            [3] => Keck
        )
```

I have an array like this. What I want is to go through these subarrays, if values [1] and [3] are the same check the maximum price, and for all others save the [0] value. If we have more subarrays with the maximum price pick random as a maximum and other put as lower. SO as output, I want to have:

```
Array
(
    [0] => E
    [1] => D
    [2] => B
    [3] => C
    [4] => A
)
```

This is my code, but it doesn't do what I want:

```
$res=array();
$Mfr= arrays_column($orginal_array, 1);
$dupes = array_diffs(array_count_values($Mfr), array(1)); // how many times a mfr sku appears [mfrsku_example] => 3
print "\nThese are repetitive values:\n[mfrsku] => (number of reps)\n";
print_r($dupes);
foreach($dupes as $key => $val){
    $temp = array_intersect_key(arrays_column($final_array, 3), array_intersect($Mfr, array($key))); 
    if(count(array_unique($temp)) < count($temp)){
        $temp = array_intersect_key(arrays_column($final_array, 2), array_intersect($Mfr, array($key)));
        $temp = array_diffs($temp, array(min($temp)));
        $res[] = array_intersect_key(arrays_column($final_array, 0), $temp);
    }else{

    }
    //$res[] = array_intersect_key(arrays_column($final_array, 0), $temp);
    //$res[] = $final_array[array_search(max($temp), $temp)][0];
}
```

Comment: [1] and [3] corresponds to `TIME` and `Keck`, isn't so?

Comment: correct @AksenP

Comment: then checking of the maximum price should not be turn on

Comment: the maximum price is checked for subarrays that have the same 1 and 3 values

Comment: these values are different

Comment: if values [1] and [3] are the same check the maximum price <- correct

Comment: your input array doesn't has the same 1 and 3 values at any index of it

Comment: I mean value[3] from one subarray should be the same as value of other [3]value od other subarray and etc

Comment: This question Needs More Clarity (and probably a better [mcve]) but they are permanently gone, so this page should go too, me thinks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_column to get all the prices and use the third parameter to make the return array associative on the "letter".
Then sort it associative with asort and the result is the array_keys of that array.

```
$price = array_column($arr, 2, 0);
asort($price);
$highest = array_intersect($price, [end($price)]); // get all with the highest price

if(count($highest)>1){ // is there more than one
    $price = array_diff($price, $highest); // remove all with highets price
    $highest = shuffle_assoc($highest); // shuffle associative from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4102803/5159168
    $price = array_merge($price, array_slice($highest,0,1)); // add one with highest price 
}
$result = array_keys($price);

var_dump($result);


// https://stackoverflow.com/a/4102803/5159168
function shuffle_assoc($list) { 
  if (!is_array($list)) return $list; 

  $keys = array_keys($list); 
  shuffle($keys); 
  $random = array(); 
  foreach ($keys as $key) { 
    $random[$key] = $list[$key]; 
  }
  return $random; 
}
```

returns:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "E"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "D"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "B"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "C"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "G" // or A, random
}
```

https://3v4l.org/GbcpA

Comment: You haven't used desired logic at all

Comment: The question is so confusing that I don't understand it. So I replicated the expected output and lets see what OP says

Comment: I dont have G in the output that i described

Comment: @ririririri because it's highest and duplicated?

Comment: just because it has the highest price

Comment: But A has the same price? So why is that kept?

Comment: as i said in the description, if two subarrays have the max price, RANDOMLY pick one as a highest

Comment: @AksenP There is nothing in the example that suggest that is the case. If that would be the case OP has failed to make an example. And you are only guessing what the output should be in the event of this. There is nothing in the question that suggests that your output is correct.

Comment: @Andreas, OP said **if values [1] and [3] are the same check the maximum price**, which means that array could has not the same [1] and [3] values. In other case this `wish` quite useless.

Comment: @AksenP But **do you know for sure**? And again, is your output really what OP has requested in such event? **NO**. Nothing has been requested.

Answer (score 0):

You can use next code for achieving a desired output:

```
$arr = array (  
  array ( 'E', 'TIME', '46.00', 'Keck', ),
  array ( 'D', 'TIME', '22.00', 'Keck', ),
  array ( 'B', 'TIME', '80.00', 'Keck', ),
  array ( 'C', 'TIME', '55.00', 'Keck', ),
  array ( 'G', 'TIME', '33.00', 'Keck', ),
  array ( 'A', 'TIME', '80.00', 'Keck', ),
  array ( 'A1', 'TIME', '80.00', 'Keck', ),
  array ( 'F', 'TIME', '35.00', 'Keck', ),

  array ( 'E2', 'TIME2', '46.00', 'Keck2', ),
  array ( 'D2', 'TIME2', '22.00', 'Keck2', ),
  array ( 'B2', 'TIME2', '76.00', 'Keck2', ),
  array ( 'C2', 'TIME2', '55.00', 'Keck2', ),
  array ( 'G2', 'TIME2', '76.00', 'Keck2', ), 
);

$res = [];
$one_three = array_unique(array_column($arr, 3, 1));         // unique pairs [1] and [3]

foreach($one_three as $one => $two){

    // get separated sets of records for each unique pair of [1] and [3]
    $tmp = [];
    foreach($arr as $subar){
        if ($subar[1] == $one && $subar[3] == $two){
            $tmp[$subar[0]] = $subar[2];
        } 
    }

    // values with max price  
    $max = max($tmp);    
    $rand_ar = [];

    foreach($arr as $subar){
        if($subar[2] == $max){
            $rand_ar[] = $subar[0]; 
        } 
    }     

    // random highest value    
    shuffle($rand_ar);                        // shuffle
    $rand_val = $rand_ar[0];                  // get one value
    $ar_without_dupes = array_diff(array_keys($tmp),$rand_ar);     // remove them all from parent array  
    $ar_without_dupes['rand'] = $rand_val;    // store random value
    $res = array_merge($res,array_flip($ar_without_dupes));
}
  $res = array_keys($res);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => E
    [1] => D
    [2] => B
    [3] => C
    [4] => G
    [5] => F
    [6] => E2
    [7] => D2
    [8] => B2
    [9] => C2
)
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/2k55m)**

In case of [yours input](https://3v4l.org/WQ53I):

```
Array
(
    [0] => E
    [1] => D
    [2] => B
    [3] => C
    [4] => G
)
```

Comment: But i dont want to have output like this, please check my description

Comment: @ririririri, it's an output for my custom input. You can apply [your input](https://3v4l.org/bUej5)

Comment: okay, but your output right now:

[keyA] =>[valueA]

what i want is

[0] = [keyA]