# Laravel cards shuffling code does not returns 52 cards

Tags: php, laravel, game-development, shuffle, playing-cards

this is my code;

following functions are used to generate a new deck, length of the deck where it will be split and random number of shuffles to be performed.

```
  public function newDeck()
  {
      $suits = ['S', 'H', 'C', 'D'];
      $values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13];

      foreach($suits as $suit)
      {
          foreach($values as $value)
          {
              $deck[$suit . $value] = $value;
          }
      }

      return $deck;
  }
  //this function gives the length where the deck will be sliced
  public function cutLength($len)
  {
      for ($i = 0; $i < 1; ++$i) {
          $cutLength[] = rand(1,$len-1);
      }

      return $cutLength;
  }

  //this function gives the number of total shuffles
  public function shuffleCount($count)
  {
      for ($i = 0; $i < 1; ++$i) {
          $shuffleCount[] = rand(1,$count);
      }

      return $shuffleCount;
  }
```

and the following code shuffles the card deck. Here I am just retrieving the card deck from a db.

```
$left = json_decode(Game::where('gamer_id',
    $request->id)->latest()->first()->game_deck, TRUE);

//set of single shuffles
$m = $game->shuffleCount(5);
for($j = 0; $j < $m[0]; $j++) {

    //count of complete deck
    $leftLength = count($left);

    //place from where the deck will be seperated
    $fullDeckCutLength = $game->cutLength($leftLength);

    //right is the lower portion of cards
    $right = array_slice($left, $fullDeckCutLength[0], $leftLength - $fullDeckCutLength[0]);

    //left is the upper portion of cards
    $left = array_slice($left, 0, $fullDeckCutLength[0]);

    //empty the full deck cut length array
    $fullDeckCutLength = [];

    //check the thickness of the cards in the right hand
    $rightLength = count($right);

    //if less than 10 cards in right hand, then this if will just place them on top of the cards in right hand
    if($rightLength < 0.2 * $leftLength) {
        $left = array_merge($right, $left);
        $right = [];
        continue;
    } else {
        //Single shuffle
        $n = $game->shuffleCount(10);

        for($i = 0; $i < $n[0]; $i++) {
            //count cards in right hand
            $rightLength = count($right);
            //determine how many cards will be slid from the top of right deck to the top of left deck
            $rightDeckCutLength = $game->cutLength($rightLength);
            //remove the cards from the top of right hand deck
            $rtl = array_slice($right, 0, $rightDeckCutLength[0]);

            //place the cards from the top of right deck to the top of left deck
            $left = array_merge($rtl, $left);

            //empty the right to left array
            $rtl = [];

            //remaining cards in the right hand deck
            $right = array_slice($right, $rightDeckCutLength[0], $rightLength - $rightDeckCutLength[0]);

            //empty the right deck cut length array
            $rightDeckCutLength = [];

            //check the thickness of the cards in the right hand
            $rightLength = count($right);
            //if the cards in RH are less than 10 then continue the loop
            if($rightLength < 0.2 * $leftLength) {
                $left = array_merge($right, $left);
                $right = [];
                $n = [];
                break;
            } elseif($i == $n[0]) {
                $left = array_merge($right, $left);
                $right = [];
                $n = [];
            }
        }
    }
}

dd($left);
```

Now this code is shuffling the cards as per intended but the issue I am getting is that the output I am getting doesnot always has 52 cards, most of the times it is 52 cards but sometimes the output is less than 52. Can someone point out the issue, please.

Comment: Although you might be using this in a Laravel application, does the `newDeck()` do everything we need to debug this? Also, what is `shuffCount()` doing, I'm not clear on it: https://3v4l.org/2WFGO

Comment: Why not just use `shuffle()`?

Comment: This is an attempt to imitate actual human playing cards shuffling behavior

Comment: @Chris newDeck() just makes a new deck and shuffleCount() just generates a random number. Please read the code.

Comment: I did. `shuffleCount` **does not** generate a random number. It generates an array of random numbers. Those are two very different things. I'm not clear why you need an array of random numbers.

Comment: Seems like the shuffle [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4102803/231316) could just be used: https://3v4l.org/FIWNG

Comment: This one doesn't works for me, my code is fine for what i need it to do. Because i don't need very good mixing

Comment: "my code is fine for what i need" - but it doesn't work all the time, right? So it isn't fine? I'm not trying to be flippant, either, just honest. Regardless, my IDE is finding several things that aren't doing what your comments say. For instance, the assignment after `//empty the full deck cut length array` isn't need because that variable is dead at that point. In fact, almost every instance of `$something = [];` except one can be removed since it isn't used. And if that code existed for a reason, I'd start there for hunting for the bug.

Comment: Tried both ways with and without emptying arrays... still same

Comment: what if just before last `dd($left)` you run check of total cards , and if less than 52 cards , do `$left = array_merge($left, $this->newDeck())` ,  or  `$left = array_merge($left, $this->presuhuffledDeck())` ... so basically add back the missing cards that somehow being thrown away during shuffle process (presume done by newb card dealer ^_^ )

Comment: "Tried both ways with and without emptying arrays" - The reason I called out the empty array stuff was that they had comments explaining what they were doing that was suspect. If that's the case, others might be. As it relates to your algorithm, are you trying to simulate someone taking a deck, cutting it into top and bottom at a random spot, placing bottom above top, and then repeating that many times?

Comment: If I understand your algorithm, I think [this](https://3v4l.org/GIUkf#v8.2.1) is an okay compromise for what you were attempting to do. 1). Cut a given deck into two parts. 2). Cut those two parts into another two parts. 3.) Combine all four parts in a different order. 4.) Repeat. Just like the human version, the more time you do this, the more it will appear to be random. If I am correct and this aligns with what you are trying to do, I'll post that as an answer.

Comment: i achieved it by including a condition at the end of the algo stating that if deck size was less than 52 it should repeat the loop, btw the problem is not in the logic rather than the random number (ChatGPT helped) ... still thankyou