Is there a way to sort an array chunk so certain values aren't in the same chunk?
I'm working on a nine player, three team drafting project. I'm trying to get the logic sorted. However, I'm running into two concerns that I'm hoping to get some help with.
I have an array of players. The player name is set as the key and the player type is set as the value. Here's what it looks like:
$players = array("Player 1" => "Mentor",
                 "Player 2" => "Mentor",
                 "Player 3" => "Mentor",
                 "Player 4" => "Player",
                 "Player 5" => "Player",
                 "Player 6" => "Player",
                 "Player 7" => "Player",
                 "Player 8" => "Player");

There should be a total of 3 teams, and each team should only have 1 "Mentor" on it.
My first concern is that my array output isn't correctly grabbing the player name.
My second concern is that I'm not sure how to logically set 1 Mentor per team.
After looking at a few posts, I know array_chunk can use the option of true for the third setting to store the previous keys, but it still doesn't seem to be working. Here's the entire script so far:
$players = array("Player 1" => "Mentor",
                 "Player 2" => "Mentor",
                 "Player 3" => "Mentor",
                 "Player 4" => "Player",
                 "Player 5" => "Player",
                 "Player 6" => "Player",
                 "Player 7" => "Player",
                 "Player 8" => "Player");
shuffle($players);
$max_players = 3;
$teams = array_chunk($players,$max_players,true);
$teamno = 1;
for ($i = 0; $i < $max_players; $i++) {
    $teamcheck = $teams[$i];
    echo 'Team '.$teamno.'<br>';
    foreach ($teamcheck as $name => $type) {
        echo $name;
    }
    echo "<br><br>";
    $teamno++;
}

For my first concern that the output isn't correctly grabbing the player name, it seems to be grabbing key values of 0-7, without the shuffle. It outputs the following:
Team 1
012

Team 2
345

Team 3
67

However, if I change $name to $type in the echo, it correctly shuffles, but only shows the player type, and not name. It outputs the following:
Team 1
PlayerMentorPlayer

Team 2
MentorPlayerMentor

Team 3
PlayerPlayer

How can I get it to correctly show the player name, and it shuffles correctly?
How can I also implement logic so that if a Mentor type already exists in that chunk portion, only bring in two other Player types, then move on?

You mention nine players but your array only contains eight. Would it not be simpler to have an array of three mentors and a separate array of six players? https://3v4l.org/Kfefl

Shuffle doesn't preserve the keys - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102777/php-random-shuffle-array-maintaining-key-value

Thank you both for that. I'll take a look and see if that helps me.
I only list 8, as there might not always be 9. There will always be at least 4, but players 5 to 9 aren't absolutely necessary.
Any potential idea on my second item to hopefully only have 1 Mentor per team?

Hi, welcome. Follow @user1191247 comment, keep a separate array for three mentors.  That's more concise than a loop, or array_reduce()

array_chunk() is not a good option as it won't give even distribution of the players. For example, if you have seven players you end up with two teams of three and one team of one, when presumably you would want one team of three and two teams of two.
I would start by splitting the Mentors and Players into separate arrays and shuffle them both:
<?php

$all = array('Player 1' => 'Mentor',
             'Player 2' => 'Mentor',
             'Player 3' => 'Mentor',
             'Player 4' => 'Player',
             'Player 5' => 'Player',
             'Player 6' => 'Player',
             'Player 7' => 'Player',
             'Player 8' => 'Player');

// separate the Players and Mentors into their own arrays
foreach ($all as $name => $type) {
    if ($type == 'Mentor') {
        $mentors[] = ['name' => $name, 'type' => $type];
    } else {
        $players[] = ['name' => $name, 'type' => $type];
    }
}

shuffle($mentors);
shuffle($players);

Then calculate the number of teams:
$max_players = 3;
$total_players = count($all);
$num_teams = ceil($total_players / $max_players);

And finally, distribute the Mentors and Players between the teams:
for ($i = 0; $i < $total_players; $i++) {
    $team = $i % $num_teams;
    $teams[$team][] = array_pop($mentors) ?? array_pop($players);
}

Here's a demo 3v4l.org.
